# How can I stop cron from deleting images I need

Tags: 7, cron, media

I have an image that is being deleted by the drupal 7 cron.

This is not good for us and I am trying to figure out how to prevent this.

As I am new to drupal I am not sure even where to begin but I am pretty sure we add the image via the core image module if that helps.

Please if anyone could help I would be most appreciative and sorry if this Q is too noob for here :)

The image is the only one in it's containing folder too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
<?php
$file->status |= FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
$file = file_save($file);
?>
```

While you save the file

**References**

[hook_insert](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_insert/7)